# button not appear in scrollview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am write code for scrollview and add button on it but button not appear in scrollview.
My code

```
tableProductScrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 442, 874, 208)];
tableProductScrollView.delegate=self;
[tableProductScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[tableProductScrollView  setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
tableProductScrollView .indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;
tableProductScrollView .pagingEnabled = YES;
tableProductScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
[tableProductScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1748,208)];
[tableProductScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:tableProductScrollView];  

CGRect frameProduct1 = CGRectMake(85, 445, 142, 150);
tableProduct1Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
tableProduct1Button.frame = frameProduct1;  
UIImage *imgProduct1= [UIImage imageNamed:@"product6-small.png"];       
[tableProduct1Button setImage:imgProduct1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
tableProduct1Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableProduct1Button.highlighted = YES;
//---add the action handler and set current class as target---
[tableProduct1Button addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(homeButtonAction)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[tableProductScrollView addSubview: tableProduct1Button];
```

please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe:

> UIButton *tableProduct1Button =
>   [UIButton
>   buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a round rect button with some color and then see if you are able to see the button or else check the frame. Or try to set an image for the highlighted state.

```
[tableProduct1Button setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```